# haproxy behavior when dns lookup returns multiple IP addresses for a server domain

Tags: docker-compose, load-balancing, haproxy

Honestly, I've tested this and I think haproxy picks the first IP address. though I'm not sure. In addition, I thought there would be some configuration I'm not aware of which I can use to balance the traffic over those IPs. so I'm decided to ask here. This is my backend block defined in the haproxy config file:

```
backend lb_webapp_backend
  http-send-name-header Host
  server webapp webapp:80 check
```

and this is the DNS lookup output from the haproxy server shell:

```
/ $ nslookup webapp
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find webapp: No answer

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   webapp
Address: 172.23.0.5
Name:   webapp
Address: 172.23.0.3
Name:   webapp
Address: 172.23.0.4
```

but the result is that all the traffic is going through one of these IP addresses.
Is there any solution to balance the traffic in a circumstance like this?

Comment: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/high-availability/active-active/dns-round-robin/

Comment: @mahyard while the question is slightly different the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68977740/1532051 should still stand. You should use a `server-template` that will generate a line for each response from the DNS resolver. The backend will then load balance across all of them.